# For accessibility (a11y) we need access to TextBlock items with the keyboard (Tab). How can we manage that?

Tags: uwp, accessibility

For our project we need to make an UWP application and it must be accessible for blind people. But we have a problem with static texts.

TextBlock is not derived from Control, so it's not Focusable. We tried to wrap it within a ContentControl, but that doesn't work either.

```
        <ContentControl
            x:Name="textBlock"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="24,0,0,24"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            IsFocusEngagementEnabled="True"
            IsTabStop="True"
            TabIndex="20">
            <TextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.           
           </TextBlock>
        </ContentControl>
```

How can we get static text into the accessibility tree so the user can navigate to it with the keyboard and can hear the text?

Comment: Not an expert on UWP applications but you shouldn't need to make the text focusable. Have you tested with a screen reader using a screen readers normal controls as things don't have to be focusable to be read if set up correctly. Hopefully someone can comment on that with regards to your specific example but having used a screen reader on several applications I wouldn't expect to focus text, yet I can still access it via normal reading methods.

Comment: I am using Narrator for reading the screen

Comment: When you use the arrow keys when holding de Caps Lock or Insert Button the text items are accessible and Narrator is reading the text.

So problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the arrow keys when holding de Caps Lock or Insert Button the text items are accessible and Narrator is reading the text.

So problem solved

Comment: Yeah exactly, that is how you would navigate normally, not everything needs to be focusable to be accessible as screen readers have special ways of accessing information.